# Error with SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I want to select the columns `TeamProjectProjectNodeName` & `TestPlanName` from the inner subquery. The inner query runs perfectly fine in fetching results from the view. But I am getting the below error, when I run the entire query as below -

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Please help me with the same.

Here is my query -

```
select 
    x.TeamProjectProjectNodeName, x.TestPlanName
from 
    (select 
         TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName,ResultOutcome, count(ResultOutcome) 
     from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[TestResultView] 
     where TestPlanName <> 'NULL'
     GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName, ResultOutcome
     order by TeamProjectProjectNodeName asc, TestPlanName asc) x
```

Thanks.

Comment: A few questions, if you run the subquery on its own does it run?  In the existing query, remove the `order by` from the subquery and place an alias on the `count()`.  Do you mean to use `<> null` or do you want `is not null`?

Comment: What data type is ResultOutcome?

Comment: ResultOutcome is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to give your `count()` an alias and `group by` aggregate function to avoid the error

```
select x.TeamProjectProjectNodeName,x.TestPlanName
from (select TeamProjectProjectNodeName,TestPlanName,ResultOutcome, count(ResultOutcome) as total from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[TestResultView] 
where TestPlanName <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName, ResultOutcome) x
```

Answer (score 4):

Bring order by out of the sub query, and name the count column like this:

```
select 
   x.TeamProjectProjectNodeName,
   x.TestPlanName,
   x.Total
from (select 
         TeamProjectProjectNodeName,
         TestPlanName,
         ResultOutcome, 
         count(*) as Total 
      from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[TestResultView] 
      where TestPlanName IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName, ResultOutcome
     ) x
order by TeamProjectProjectNodeName asc, TestPlanName asc
```

I have also changed your `WHERE` syntax to `IS NOT NULL` as @bluefeet suggested, as I imagine this is what you actually require.

Comment: I would suggest possibly changing or making a note to change the `TestPlanName <> 'NULL'` to `TestPlanName is not null`. If they are really testing for null.  The first will not work unless they are actually storing null as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
select x.TeamProjectProjectNodeName,x.TestPlanName
from (select top 100 percent TeamProjectProjectNodeName,TestPlanName,ResultOutcome, count(ResultOutcome) SomeAlias from [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[TestResultView] 
where TestPlanName <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, TestPlanName, ResultOutcome
order by TeamProjectProjectNodeName asc, TestPlanName asc) x
```

You cannot have a order by in your inner select unless you specify top and the count() should have an alias.

Comment: You might want to remove the `order by` from the subquery. :)

Comment: You can use it with a `top 100 percent`. But is that useful? ;-)

Comment: Yeah I have to agree it is horrible practice.